# aggregation per each attribute value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to group each column with id and find minimum of day_time.

**code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set, min, col, struct

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Data Transformation") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("day_time", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("country", StringType(), True),
    StructField("activities", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("is_stream", StringType(), True)
])

# Sample data
data = [("1", datetime.strptime("2024-01-08T13:14:41", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') , "US", ["fun"], "FALSE"),
        ("1", datetime.strptime("2024-01-08T13:14:42", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') , "US", ["action","adventure"], "TRUE"),
        ("1", datetime.strptime("2024-01-08T13:14:44", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') , "US", ["action","adventure"], "TRUE")
]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Group by "id" and all non-"id" columns
grouped_df = df.groupBy("id", "country", "activities", "is_stream").agg(
    min("day_time").alias("min_time")
)

grouped_df.show(truncate=False)


# Combine the details into the desired JSON format
result_df = grouped_df.groupBy("id").agg(
    collect_set(
        struct(
            col("country").alias("key"),
            col("min_time").alias("timestamp")
        )
    ).alias("country_details")
)

# Show the result
result_df.show(truncate=False)
```

**Data after groupBy("id", "country", "activities", "is_stream"):**

```
+---+-------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
|id |country|activities         |is_stream|min_time           |
+---+-------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
|1  |US     |[fun]              |FALSE    |2024-01-08 13:14:41|
|1  |US     |[action, adventure]|TRUE     |2024-01-08 13:14:42|
+---+-------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
```

**Final result from above code:**

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
|id |details                                               |
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{US, 2024-01-08 13:14:41}, {US, 2024-01-08 13:14:42}]|
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected results:** I need time value of 2024-01-08 13:14:41 which is minimum for combination of id=1 and country=US, not both values (ie. 2024-01-08 13:14:41 and 2024-01-08 13:14:42 as above.

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
|id |details                                               |
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{US, 2024-01-08 13:14:41}]
+---+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Essentially I need to find min value of `day_time` for each column by grouping with `id`. I was planning to extend above code of `collect_set`, by adding separate collect_set for all remaining columns `activities`,`is_stream`. ie. if we consider `activities` column, for `[fun]` we need `2024-01-08 13:14:41` and for `[action, adventure]` we need `2024-01-08 13:14:42`

```
+---+-------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
|id |country                       |  activities         
+---+-------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
|1  |[{"US", 2024-01-08 13:14:41}] | [{"fun", 2024-01-08 13:14:41}, {"action", 2024-01-08 13:14:42}, {"adventure", 2024-01-08 13:14:42}]   
+---+-------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, for each `id` value, you want to find the row with the earliest timestamp.

You have essentially 2 solutions in this case, depending if it is possible that there are 2 timestamps that are the minimal timestamps in a single id.

1. Using a `groupby`:

```
res = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    min(struct(
        "day_time", 
        "id", 
        "country"
    )).alias("row_with_min_timestamp")
)
```

The reason this works is because when you calculate the min of a struct the comperation is done using the first field. (And then the second and so fourth)
You should also look at `F.min_by`
2. Using `window`s

```
df = df.withColumn("min_timestamp", F.min("day_time").over(Window.partitionBy("id"))
df = df.filter(F.col("day_time") == F.col("min_timestamp"))
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**
Apparently, I didn't understand right.
If you want to find the min timestamp of the tuple `(id, col)` for each col, I'd do it this way:

```py
desired_cols = ["country", "activities", "is_stream"]

result = None

for col in desired_cols:
    min_timestamp_df = df.groupby("id").agg(F.min(F.struct("day_time", col)).alias(f"{col}_min_timestamp"))
    
    if result is None:
        result = min_timestamp_df
    else:
        result = result.join(min_timestamp_df, on="id", how="full_outer")
```

This way, `result` should have these columns: ["id", "country_min_timestamp", "activities_min_timestamp", "is_stream_min_timestamp"].

`"country_min_timestamp"` for instance, will contain the `"country"` that corresponds to the min timestamp, and the same for the other columns.

Hope this is it.

Comment: not only group on id, but groping is on id and each column. for ex: group(id, country) and get min(day_time), group(id, activities)  and get min(day_time),  group(id, is_stream)  and get min(day_time). I get that with 2nd approach we can get the min(day_time) values for each group when we add other column with `id`, but not sure with that how to produce desired result.

Comment: @user16798185 I added an "*EDIT:*" section, see if this solves your problem.

Comment: just did this --> for c in desired_cols:
    df = df.withColumn("min_time_"+c, min("day_time").over(Window.partitionBy("id",c)))